# Download file from url using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, download

How can I download a file from web (e.g. a pdf file - http:/addons.cursecdn.com/files/612/825/SC1_Remake_Installation_Guide.pdf) to the client in MVC? What I tried:

```
    public FileResult Download()
    {
        const string name = "http://addons.cursecdn.com/files/612/825/SC1_Remake_Installation_Guide.pdf";
        const string type = "application/pdf";

        return new FilePathResult(name, type)
        {
            FileDownloadName = "SC1_Remake_Installation_Guide.pdf"
        };
    }
```

This is giving me only the error message that it 'is not a valid virtual path'..

Comment: You can always just link directly to the file...

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible.  You can't return a `FileResult` without the data being in memory.  You can point to a local file path and the framework will read the file in memory and take care of that heavy lifting for you.  Or you can simply hand it a byte array from a file you read in memory yourself.  In this case, you could use the `HttpClient` to download the file and then serve up the file from memory.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys. Just realized this was a dumb idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about redirecting the client to the pdf's URL? Seems like an ok solution.

Use a regular ActionResult and use a Redirect like the following.

```
    return Redirect("http://addons.cursecdn.com/files/612/825/SC1_Remake_Installation_Guide.pdf");
```

Comment: there could be a case when user cant access URL of file, for example using webservice access is permited only to server with project, but user trying to access it gets `Access not allowed` from web service